# Treasury pallet how to make payouts in native asset?

Tags: pallet-treasury

On release 1.3.0 the type AssetKind and Paymaster where added to the treasury pallet which I guess provides the ability to pay treasury proposals in different kinds of assets through the assets pallet. My question is what if I also want to enable the native asset as one of the assets to be used to pay proposals, in addition to other assets? The native asset is not part of the assets pallet, so what would be the best way to go about doing this? Are there any examples I could look at?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your native currency is comming from `pallet-balances` and other assets from `pallet-assets` you could create two instances of `pallet-treasury`, where:

```
impl pallet-treasury::Config<Instance1> {
...
AssetKind: Balances (pallet-balances),
}
```

and

```
impl pallet-treasury::Config<Instance2> {
...
AssetKind: Assets (pallet-assets),
}
```

EDIT: To prevent two separate instances you could also use ([PR](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/pull/2033) not merged yet) [`NativeOrWithId`](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/a3bd5870f325e13335d7eb91d42968b5d1251903/substrate/frame/support/src/traits/tokens/fungible/union_of.rs#L41) that wraps around the two.